# EF code first CRUD using WCF Service

Tags: wcf, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I need to implement EF code-first CRUD operation using WCF service and consume that service in ASP.NET MVC

You can download the code from https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8wo1tBk-CwPQlA3N2FTOUVIVzA/edit?usp=sharing

Please guide me on this, I have implemented WCF service and EF code first and tested it using WCF test client, it is working fine but when I try to consume it from ASP.NET MVC after hosting it in IIS then different kinds of error coming

For your reference code is given below

**Service contract**

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IPerson
{
    [OperationContract]      
    List<Person> GetAllPersons();
    [OperationContract]     
    Person GetPersonsByID(int PID);
    [OperationContract]       
    int InsertPerson(Person oPerson);
    [OperationContract]
    int UpdatePerson(Person oPerson);
    [OperationContract]
    int DeletePerson(Person oPerson);

}
```

**Person Class as data contract**

```
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]//(IsReference = true)
public class Person
{
    [DataMember]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
}
```

Context class:

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DataContext(): base("DataContext")
    {
        Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;
        Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = true;
        Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = true;
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
}
```

Service implementation class:

```
public class PersonServices : IPerson
{
    public List<Person> GetAllPersons()
    {
        List<Person> lstp = new List<Person>();

        try
        {
            using (var ctx = new DataContext())
            {
                 lstp = ctx.Persons.ToList();
            }
            return lstp;
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            MyFaultException theFault = new MyFaultException();
            theFault.Reason = "Some Error " + exp.Message.ToString();

            throw new FaultException<MyFaultException>(theFault);
        }
    }

    public Person GetPersonsByID(int PID)
    {
        Person oprsn = new Person();

        using (var ctx = new DataContext())
        {
            oprsn = ctx.Persons.Find(PID);
        }

        return oprsn;
    }

    public int InsertPerson(Person oPerson)
    {
        int rtrnValue = 0;

        using (var db = new DataContext())
        {
            db.Persons.Add(oPerson);
            rtrnValue = db.SaveChanges();
        }

        return rtrnValue;
    }
}
```

Let me know about this

Error I am getting is : 1. Can not create database but its working fine when WCF is unit tested but problem coming when consumed from MVC

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: could you please include the person class as well as the error(s)

Comment: @ ozidom , person class added

Comment: @patel , Some Error An exception occurred while initializing the database. See the InnerException for details. and some time Data base not created but WCF service working when it is unit tested but problem is coming when consumed from MVC

Comment: @ozidom , Patel :  you can download code from https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8wo1tBk-CwPQlA3N2FTOUVIVzA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Must be an authorization issue. No privileges to create a database from IIS. When it says "See the InnerException", **look at the inner exception**.